# PHP sessions not initiated in Kohana https site

Tags: php, session, https, kohana

In our PHP Kohana Website, PHP sessions are not being initialized in https site (Kohana sessions works fine). The same works fine in http as well as in the local machine. We feel it is something related to configurations. If this issue is related to configurations, what are the config file I have to dig into else what might be the problem ?

I tried changing sessions.auto_start to 1 from 0, but it didn't work.

Below is the logic where Sessions are not being initialized.

`

```
session_start();
$digit = '';
$keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
for($x = 10; $x <= 130; $x += 30) {
    $digit .= ($num = $keys[array_rand($keys)]);
}
$_SESSION['captchaCodeValue'] = $digit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by moving the php session in to Kohana sesion, since I was not able to find what is wrong with the php session and the relevent configuration file to be changed.